# What is the default behavior of the diamond operator

Tags: java, diamond-operator

I remember seeing a declaration something like the following:

`private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(<>.class);`

The advantage was that it could be pasted from class to class without accidentally being a logger for another class.

Now, I can't get that to compile, the syntax must be wrong. So what exactly does <> resolve to on its own (not ArrayList<>(), etc.)?

Thank you

Update:

My assertion that it is legal syntax comes from:

1. I saw it out on the web as a legal and nifty trick.
2. Both I and a colleague pasted it into IntelliJ with Java 7 and it compiled correctly.

That said, I can't find a search that will get me to that page again, and I can't get it to compile now! So I'm hoping someone with compiler or Java spec knowledge can definitively say if it is valid and what the default is.

Comment: Nothing. It is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: As far as I know, `<>.class` is not and has never been legal. The diamond operator (introduced in Java 7) is only used as in your last example (`new ArrayList<>()`) to indicate that generic type parameters for constructor calls should be inferred. (The absence of the diamond operator indicates construction of a raw type.)

Comment: I think some IDEs might hide a type with that syntax, but it's still actually there?

Answer (score 3):

Back in Java 5 and 6, when you had to declare a new instance of a generic class*, you had to use the following syntax.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

There was no type inference at declaration time for generics.

With the advent of [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), the compiler learned a trick or two about type inference.

If the compiler *can* infer it, then using the diamond operator `<>` as it's called will produce the same result in Java 7 and up as the code above:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

There are situations, of course, where it can't.  This is borrowed from the linked example above.

> ```
> List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
> list.add("A");
> // The following statement should fail since addAll expects
> // Collection<? extends String>
>
> list.addAll(new ArrayList<>());
> ```

What you've got here is invalid code:

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(<>.class);
```

You actually need to pass a concrete `Class` to that method, and Java isn't going to be able to infer it for you in that context.

<sup>*: I don't recall if it was as bad with generic methods, but I didn't do a lot of development with Java 6 back in the day.</sup>